# Указать путь к БД в коннекшнстринге

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть connectionstring где прописан путь к БД таким образом `Data Source=C:\dev\WebApplication\DbTest.sdf`, понятное дело, что если перенести приложение в другую папку, то путь к БД будет не актуален. Сам солюшин лежит в `C:\dev\WebApplication` , вопрос в том - как указать путь, чтобы при переносе папки `WebApplication` не нужно было каждый раз менять строку подключения ?

Comment: укажи просто имя базы без пути.Data Source=DbTest.sdf

Comment: @xSx пробовал, не выходит

Comment: а так? `"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DbTest.sdf"`

Comment: в кавычки возьмите)

Comment: Не, ни кавычки ни |DataDirectory| не помогают. Вообще не пойму в чем дело

Comment: У меня работает. Попробуйте так тогда уж @"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) +"\\DbTest.sdf";

Comment: В первом лайне всегда хранится строка запуска, т.е. путь. Берем приписываем. Часто пользуюсь в мелких проектах.

Answer (score 1):

Как правило в строке подключения указывают имя сервера и название базы, а не путь к ней. SQL Server уже сам заботится о поиске необходимых файлов. Пример:

```
"Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;User Id=USER;Password=PWD
```

Если прям кровь из носу необходимо файл БД, то лучше задавать относительный путь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я вот как раз и хочу понять как относительный путь указать ? Тут в том и проблема, что именно к файлу нужно указать доступ.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey а в чём проблема указать относительный путь?

Comment: Обратите внимание: он использует SQL Server CE. Это - файловая СУБД!